# What would MySQL statement be if looking up details from a unique ID in my database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to print out details from the database with a unique ID which is taken from the URL.

I've used the `$_GET` array to get the event ID from the URL, but how would i look up the details of that event in the SQL statement? I've attempted it below but i don't think it's right. When I run the code, the page comes up blank.

```
<?php 

$eventID = clean_string($db_server, $_GET['eventid']);

$query = "SELECT eventname, eventimage, eventdate FROM events WHERE eventID=$eventID"; 

 $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die(mysql_error($db_server)); 

 if (!$result) die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($db_server)); 

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

 }

mysqli_free_result($result);

?>
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code?  Do you get an error or unexpected results?

Comment: If you're already using MySQLi, consider using prepared statements

Comment: nothing, the page is blank

Comment: put something in your while() loop then.  echo 'found something!';

Comment: what should i put in the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

[**mysqli_query**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns a mysqli_result [**object**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php).

[**mysqli_fetch_array**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) returns the result rows as both an associative or a numeric array.

TRY

```
// Numeric array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
       echo $row[0];
       echo $row[1];
     //etc
 }
// Associative array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
       echo $row["eventname"];
       echo $row["eventimage"];
     //etc
 }
```